# Render flatlist items over each other(overlap)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I wanna achieve what you can see in image below, but I have no idea to make flat list items overlap each other:
[image]

forget about the right and left icons, I'm just asking for a way for a middle container which has cards rendering on each other.  tnx in advance

Comment: Did you try adding negative margin and incremental zIndex for the items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/sponaneous-salsa

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'flex-end', backgroundColor:'white', paddingTop:10, paddingBottom:10}}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
          <View style={[styles.shadow, {backgroundColor:'red', borderTopLeftRadius:40, borderBottomLeftRadius:40}]}>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
              First
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', borderBottomWidth:0, borderColor:'white'}}>
          <View style={[styles.shadow, {backgroundColor:'red', borderTopLeftRadius:40, borderBottomLeftRadius:40}]}>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
              second  
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor:'red', borderBottomWidth:0, borderColor:'white'}}>
          <View style={[styles.shadow, {backgroundColor:'red', borderTopLeftRadius:40, borderBottomLeftRadius:40}]}>
            <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
              third
            </Text> 
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  shadow:{
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 4,  
    elevation: 5
  }
});
```

Comment: it needs to be a little modified in order to be used in flatlist render item because e.g first index in your exmaple has different style than others. but it gave me the idea how to implement my component. tnx bro